# Why does the Sum() function in (My)SQL return double the value I expect?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework2

I need sum of two different columns from two different tables, being `tbl_bill` and `tbl_receipt`.

**tbl_receipt**

```
 id receipt_no  member_id   receipt_amount
 1  21001         21        20500
 2  21002         21        200
```

**tbl_member**

```
  id    name
  21    priya
```

**tbl_invoice**

```
 id bill_no  order_id   member_id     bill_value
 1  30001       30          21          20928
 2  0002501     25          21          12030
```

I want answer in this way

```
member_id  member_name  receipt_sum  bill_sum   
21         priya        20700         32958
```

I tried doing left join but it doubles the sum value. Can any one help me out?

```
$adapter = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();
       $orderTable = new TableGateway('tbl_receipt', $adapter);
       $sqlSelect = $orderTable->getSql()->select();
       $sqlSelect->columns(array('id'=>'id','bill_amount'=>'bill_total','sum_receipt_amount'=>new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('SUM(tbl_receipt.receipt_amount)'))); 
       $sqlSelect->join('tbl_member','tbl_member.id = tbl_receipt.member_id', array('member_id'=>'id','member_name'=>'name'),'LEFT');
     //  $sqlSelect->join('tbl_receipt','tbl_receipt.member_id = tbl_bill.member_id', array('receipt_id'=>new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('(tbl_receipt.receipt_amount)')),'LEFT');


       $sqlSelect->group('tbl_member.id');
       $resultSet = $orderTable->selectWith($sqlSelect);
        //echo"<pre>";

   // print_r($resultSet); die;
  return $resultSet;
```

Comment: Please providing your existing query for clarity.

Comment: *"I tried doing left join but it doubles the sum value."* - where is it? Maybe you did an error somewhere and we don't know that; "you" do.

Comment: *"I need sum of two different columns of two different tables"* - which 2 tables? There are 3 here.

Comment: is this codeigniter?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner zend f2

Comment: tbl_bill and tbl_receipt

Comment: Share your tables and data, or examples of it doubling - please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL You  should left join on the result for sum

```
select m.id, m.name,t1.sum_amount, t2.sum_total
from tbl_member m  
left join (
  select member_id, sum(receipt_amount) sum_amount 
  from tbl_receipt
  group by member_id
) t1 on t1.member_id = m.member_id 
left  join (
  select member_id, sum(total) sum_total
  from tbl_invoice
  group by member_id
) t2  on t2.t1.member_id = m.member_id
```

Comment: The main point here is that you're using a subquery rather than it just being a left join.

Comment: I'm using two left  join on aggregated  result  ..  so avoid the duplication related  to the join with the non aggregated  row  ..